# VBA code to pull multiple sheets and paste them in master spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a bit of trouble with this macro.  I am trying to have the macro search for a string of letters "Forcacc" in the filename and copy and paste the data into a blank spreadsheet, all on top of each other.

I had this code working for a similar task and in trying to alter it for this task I can't get it to work.  I think I am most struggling with the loop and I can't get any of it to run to test it.  This code was copied from someone else's work, I am really quite beginner on writing VBA code.

I think the comments make it pretty clear, what I am looking for.  I don't think the original working code had a "Do" anywhere in the code, but it comes up as an error now if I attempt to leave it out. It still shows a "loop without do" error for me.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineDataFiles()

Dim DataBook As Workbook, OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
Dim MaxNumberFiles As Long, FileIdx As Long, _
    LastDataRow As Long, LastDataCol As Long, _
    HeaderRow As Long, LastOutRow As Long
Dim DataRng As Range, OutRng As Range

'initialize constants
HeaderRow = 2 'assume headers are always in row 1
LastOutRow = 1

'set up the output workbook
Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(1)


    'What file to find
    Dim myPath
    myPath = "Q:\.All Kiwiplan SCS Plants\Plants\Aston\2018\2018-06\"   '<< folder/path
    Dim myFile
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*ForcAcc*")

    'loop through all files
    Do Until myFile = ""
    For FileIdx = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count

    'open the file and assign the workbook/worksheet
    Set DataBook = myFile
    'Workbooks.Open (TargetFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
    Set DataSheet = Sheets("PaperWidth Data Input")

    'identify row/column boundaries
    LastDataRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastDataCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'if this is the first go-round, include the header
    If FileIdx = 1 Then
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    'if this is NOT the first go-round, then skip the header
    Else
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1 + LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    Loop
End If

    'copy the data to the outbook
    DataRng.Copy OutRng

    'close the data book without saving
    DataBook.Close False

    'update the last outbook row
    LastOutRow = OutSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Next FileIdx

'let the user know we're done!
MsgBox ("Combined " & TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count & " files!")

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use [an indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) to help sort this out.  Indent your code properly, then make sure the `Do` and `Loop` are on the same indentation level.  Same with the `For FileIdx` and `Next FileIdx`. You currently have 2 different loops interleaved, which is why you're getting the compile errors.

Comment: You also have your `Loop` inside your `If FileIdx = 1 Then` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The basic outline of Dir is

```
Dim myFile
myFile = Dir(myPath & "*ForcAcc*")
Do Until myFile = ""
:::
:::
'Next FileIdx << take this out of where it is, and put in these two lines
    myFile = Dir    '<<< add this line to have myFile be set to the next file
Loop        '<<< add this line to Loop the do until blank
```

Now the inner loop on FileIdx should have the following changes

```
        'Loop  <<remove this
    End If  '<< move this over one indent to right
Next FileIdx '<< add this here
```